# Confused on how to create a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile and I am a bit stuck.

So far I have been compiling my 3 files (2 headers and one main program) as such:

```
gcc -c phypages.c -o phypages.o
gcc -c pagetable.c -o pagetable.o
gcc -c analysis.c -o analysis.o
gcc analysis.o phypages.o pagetable.o -o analysis
```

I would like to make a Makefile to help me out with this. When I compile and link the files without a Makefile everything works fine, however when I try to make a Makefile I get a bunch of errors. Could you give me some tips on how to go about making a basic Makefile?

Comment: If you want some help on your problem you should show your Makefile and what errors you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start:

```
# Binary name
NAME    = analysis

# Compiler settings
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  += -Wall -Wextra
CFLAGS  += -Werror

# Source files
SRCS    = phypages.c        \
          pagetable.c       \
          analysis.c

# Object files
OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

RM  = rm -f


# Default rule, it should call all your rules that create
# an executable, or build a library...
# Here, it calls only the $(NAME) rule, that builds `analysis`
all: $(NAME)

# Rule to build your object files and link them into a binary
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

# Rule to remove object files
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

# Rule to remove binary, calls the 'clean' rule first
fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

# Rule to remove object files and binary, then re-build everything
re: fclean all

# Rules that are not linked with a filename should be listed here
.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

You can then run `make analysis` or simply `make` to build your program.

Next time you change a file, run `make` again and only the file you changed will be re-compiled, instead of the whole project.